# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) when trying to reach 1 of 3 apps

Tags: nginx, debian, django, gunicorn

I have two Django apps running on my Debian server with Gunicorn.
One running on port 80(app1), the other on 84(app2). app1 is working fine. But when trying to open app2, I get a 502 Bad Gateway from Nginx. Both their configs are almost identical. I have no idea why this isnt working. I also have a third app running but that's running on Flask IIRC.

sites-available/app2

```
server {
listen 84;
server_name app2;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
}

location /static/ {
    root /home/app1;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
}
```

sites-available/app1

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1;
    
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
    
        location /static/ {
            root /home/django;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
       location /bestanden/ {
            root /home/django/files;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
    }
```

/etc/systemd/system/app1.service

```
[Unit]
Description=App1
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/app1/bin/start-app.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/app1/bin/start-app1.sh

```
cd /home/app1/app
echo "Activating"
source /home/app1/env/bin/activate
echo "Starting"
# conf.py contains some environment variables for the app
gunicorn -c "/home/app1/env/bin/gunicorn.conf.py" app1.wsgi
```

/etc/systemd/system/pricescraper.server

```
[Unit]
Description=App2
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/app2/bin/start-app.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/app2/bin/start-app2

```
cd /home/app2/app/
source /home/app2/venv/bin/activate
gunicorn -c "/home/app2/venv/bin/gunicorn.conf.py" app2.wsgi -b 192.168.188.43:7000
```

When I take a look at error.log I get this:
[error] 1560#1560: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.188.199, server: app2, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:7000/", host: "192.168.188.43:84"

I have no idea what this means, googling it ended up on a question where they were using sockets and just removed the ULR prefix, which doesnt apply to me. The weirdest part is when I open 192.168.188.43:7000 I does open the index.html but without any static files loading, which includes necessary JS so I can't test the backend.

Please, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it wasn't supposed to bind to 192.168... but to 127.0.0.1